# why unlink function doesn't delete my file in node.js and nitrous.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, nitrousio

I'm trying to delete an existing file but each time I get error why ?

```
fs.unlink('test.txt',function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Update : console.log(err) -> null
I'm using nitrous.io box

Update 2 : tried same program on my Mac Osx it works so seems there is a problem with nitrous.io box

Comment: And what does the error say (please don't say `error`) ?

Comment: do console.log(err) might help tracking down what the problem is.

Comment: @Ben thanks I'm beginner just updated and it gives null I'm using nitrous.io box

Comment: @adeneo : I updated err gives null

Comment: @user310291: Then you're not getting an error! Does the file still exist after the execution of this?

Comment: yes the file is still there that's why I ask the question in the first place :)

Comment: @user310291: so test.txt and the node.js script files are in the same directory?

Comment: What directory is the file in and what directory are you running your script from? As it is now, it will delete `test.txt` from the current working directory, not the directory with the script.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm executing the script within the script directory. I can delete by hand.

Comment: @loganfsmyth tried same program on my Mac Osx it works so seems there is a problem with nitrous.io box